# Argument 'ClockOnController' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, angularjs-controlleras

Hi I've been having some problems refactoring my controllers into their own snippets

I want the controllers to inherit the dependencies from my initial app declaration.

```
    "use strict";
    angular.module('clockOn', ['angular-contextual-date','logon','milli','mobile','ClockOnController','Auth','ngStorage'])
```

I need these dependencies to flow through my controllers.

```
      angular.module('clockOn').controller('LogonController',              ['$rootScope','$scope','$location','$localStorage','Auth', 
function($rootScope, $scope, $location, $localStorage,Auth){
```

creates unknown provider errors --I'm assuming the dependencies aren't flowing down--

```
    angular.module('clockOn',[]).controller()
```

creates undefined function 'controllerName' errors -In this scenario I'm assuming I'm redefining the app and hence loosing the other controllers-

Here's two of the controllers

```
(function (){
angular.module('clockOn',['Auth','angular-contextual-date'])  
.controller('ClockOnController',     ['$http','Auth','contextualDateService' ,function      ($http,Auth,contextualDateService){
      this.user = Auth.getTokenClaims().user; //authorised is a property of the controller 
      contextualDateService.config.fullDateFormats.thisMonth = "MMM d 'at'  h:mm a ";    
      this.shifts = getShifts(this);

    function getShifts(clockOnCtrl){
      var date = new Date();
      var curr_date = Date.now();
      var week_from_now = Date.now()+"7";

    $http({
      method: 'GET', 
      url: '/shifts', 
      params: {"user_id":clockOnCtrl.user._id,
      "start_at":curr_date,
      "finish_at":week_from_now} 
   }).
   then(function(res){           
     if (typeof res !== 'undefined'){
       console.log(res.data);
       clockOnCtrl.shifts = res.data;         
   }},
   function(error){
     console.log(error)
   });  
}

}]);
})();
```

My index file

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html class="container" ng-app="clockOn"> <!-- ng-app tells the html page which app/module it belongs too runs the store module on load-->
    <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width , initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/bootstrap.min.css"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/custom.css"/>
    </head>

    <body>  
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../resources/jquery.min.js"></script>    
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../resources/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../resources/bower_components/angular-contextual-date/dist/angular-contextual-date.js"></script>     
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../modules/app.js"></script>       
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../modules/logon.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../modules/tasks.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../services/milli.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../services/auth.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../modules/mobile.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../modules/shifts.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../modules/layout-components.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../resources/bower_components/ngstorage/ngStorage.min.js"></script>    
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../controllers/controller-clockOn.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../controllers/controller-logon.js"></script>    
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../controllers/controller-tasks.js"></script> 

<div class="container" ng-controller="ClockOnController as clockOnCtrl">
  <div class= "" ng-controller="LogonController as logonCtrl">
  <logon-form></logon-form>
  <top-menu></top-menu>    
  <div class="page-header" ng-show="token">
    <h2 class="">Welcome {{clockOnCtrl.user.name | uppercase}}
      <small>You currently have {{clockOnCtrl.shifts.length}} shifts</small>
    <h2>
  </div>
  <shifts-list></shifts-list>
  <custom-footer></custom-footer> 
  </div>
</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

The error Argument 'ClockOnController' is not a function, got undefined

Comment: you haven't provided a name for the controller, thats why 'undefined function 'controllerName'

Comment: I wanted to keep the code short heres a full example of my LogonController

Comment: do a ctrl-f for 'controllerName' Where you're using that, you essentially shouldn't be because that kind of function does not exist. I tried to find it your code but couldn't :/

Comment: controllerName is the name of the controller ie the error I'm getting Argument 'ClockOnController' is not a function, got undefined

Comment: `angular.module('clockOn',['Auth','angular-contextual-date'])`: that redefines the 'clockOn' module entirely. If you're doing that in every JS file, you end up with a single clockOn module containing only the components added in the last JS file. Define your module only once.

Comment: thanks for clearing that up